# Remove (filter out) objects from queryset

Tags: django, django-orm

I'd like to remove 3 objects from my queryset. This working with the help of an extra list, but im pretty sure there should be a better way to do this with the [QuerySet API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/). However I didnt figure out how yet:

What I'm doing:

```
ranks = Rank.objects.all()
remove_ranks = ['Field Marshall', 'Military Attache', 'Mercenary Recruiter']
new_ranks =[]

for rank in ranks:
    if not rank.name in remove_ranks:
        new_ranks.append(rank)
```

How can I do this using the Django API ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try

```
remove_ranks = ['Field Marshall', 'Military Attache', 'Mercenary Recruiter']
Rank.objects.exclude(name__in=remove_ranks)
```

what does it do?

`.exclude` is the opposite of `.filter`

`name__in` is the equivalent of a IN-Statement in SQL

This should produce a sql query something along the line

```
Select * from rank where name not in ('Field Marshall', 'Military Attache', 'Mercenary Recruiter')
```

Comment: Thanks this works indeed. Could you give me a small example of what "in" actualy does, since so far i jsut tried by using the exclude
Edit: thanks for updating post

Comment: Does my update clarify what they do? If not I'm happy to extend my post. In any case have a quick look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/
which will give you a overview of the Django QuerySet Api

Comment: btw: If this answer seems to be correct to you, could you please accept it? :-)

Comment: Had to wait another 10 minutes before i could accept :)